Mass change in Adobe Acrobat
I have about 1000 PDF documents in which I have to change the e-mail address and I work with Adobe Acrobat Pro. Is there a way to do this via the system?
Does anyone have a tipp for me?
I have already tried my luck with the "Action Wizard" but it doesn't seem to be suitable for this either, because I can't find a point to replace the data.
Greetings
